# Number of threads per core in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I simply want to clarify something that appear confusing to me on the use of threads in Spark.

Can someone confirm that in Spark:

> 1. Each Core can only run one thread or at least that a ***task slot*** correspond to ***one core and one core only and never a thread***.
> 2. The case of the local mode is an exception. It uses available thread to simulate the available task slots in cluster mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core in Spark is a thread that can be assigned for processing tasks and this meaning doesn't change that much between `local` and distributed mode.

In practice Spark uses a lot of more threads for purposes other than tasks processing including, but not limited to:

- Processing heartbeats.
- Spark UI.
- Broadcasting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SPARK_WORKER_CORES parameter in spark stand-alone mode for runnning more than one thread per core. This variable is set in the spark-env.sh file.

The word core is easy to get confused with the actual cpu core, but SPARK_WORKER_CORES parameter is not related to the cpu core.

(Looks like asked a long time ago, since I was having the same question, posting the answer here)